# Lambda expressions and implicit typing

Tags: vb.net, lambda

Ok so after spending the last several years coding in c# I am now at a new job and using VB.net. I am trying to figure out how I would write lambda expressions and I think I have it somewhat figured out, for example:

In C# I could write

```
var checkedItems = lvwCharges.Items.Where(item => item.Checked)
```

And in VB.Net it woulde be:

```
Dim checkedItems = lvwCharges.Items.Where(Function(item) item.Checked)
```

So, I think I have the syntax down but my question is why does VB.Net treat "item" as an Object instead of a ListViewItem which is what it is? Do I have to cast to a listviewitem somewhere in my lamda? It seems like it should know that item is a ListViewItem so I am not sure what is going on.

Any insights would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Your code of C# can't compile, because `ListViewItemCollection` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<ListViewItem>`.

Comment: Thanks Ripple, that would be it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListViewItemCollection` does not implement `IEnumerable<ListViewItem>`, so `item` in your LINQ functions will not be implicitly typed (and therefore will be of type `Object`).

**This is easy to fix.** Simply cast the `Items` collection before you attempt to use any lambda expressions:

```
var checkedItems = lvwCharges.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Where(item => item.Checked);
```

Furthermore, if the VB example above compiles as-is, your project has `Option Strict Off`, which *will* allow `checkedItems` to be implicitly typed -- as an `IEnumerable(Of ListViewItem)`.

If it doesn't compile (probably because the project is set with `Option Strict On`) you'll need to specify the type of `checkedItems`, but not of `item`; since it is now implicitly typed from the result of the `Cast(Of T)`.

```
Dim checkedItems As IEnumerable(Of ListViewItem) = ...
```

That said, there's nothing preventing you from specifying `item`'s type explicitly in either language:

```cs
var checkedItems = lvwCharges.Items
    .Cast<ListViewItem>()
    .Where((ListViewItem item) => item.Checked)
```

Or

```vb
Dim checkedItems = lvwCharges.Items _
    .Cast(Of ListViewItem)() _
    .Where(Function(item As ListViewItem) item.Checked)
```

Comment: Thank you. I realize that "item" should be implicitly typed, however it is NOT and shows up as type "Object", not ListViewItem. The intellisense does not pick up the .Checked property and only shows properties off of type object. Thanks for the syntax on explicitly typing.

Comment: Maybe it is a general problem with my installation... I am not seeing any errors being underlined in blue in my source files either.

Comment: @JoeKrueger: I just realized, based on the comments on your question, that I was wrong. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Ahhh, "The ListViewItemCollection" does not implement IEnumerable<ListViewItem>". That says it all. Thank you!